# Multiple databases and single/multiple codebase: Performance differences

Tags: amazon-ec2, server, system, scalability, devops

I have a product (say X) hosted in single Amazon EC2 instance that's used by three customers (say A, B and C). At present, I have 3 databases and 3 codebase accessed through sub-domains, like: a.productx.com, b.productx.com and c.productx.com

Technically, I need different databases for customers A, B and C but codebase can be the same (except for the database config part). Is it wise to have single codebase and three databases? For ex: if a customer logs-in from a.productx.com, I will use the A database; when it is b.productx.com, I will use the B database; when it is c.productx.com, I will use the C database. **The codebase is common for all.**

It would save a lot my time (easy upgrades, maintenance) and space, but I'm not sure if there would be any performance hit. In other words, though customers would hit the server through different sub-domains, they all will eventually be served from single codebase. Would this cause performance issues compared to having multiple codebases? I'm not a server/systems person and would like your advise.

Thanks!

Comment: got the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361964/multiple-databases-looking-at-single-php-codebase-issues thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The difference regarding to performance would be that instead of having 3 servers, each serving one customer, you would have one server handling the requests of all 3 customers. If you already have enough load on your 3 servers to significantly utilize them (CPU or memory), migrating to just one server (of the same size) will have a negative impact on performance.

So if your server load is light, you may be able to handle all 3 customers on one server of the same size. Alternatively you may need to use a larger server (more CPUs, more RAM).

As to your particular setup, it might be difficult to utilize just one server and to connect to the correct database depending on the domain that your user is coming throut. You need to think how your solution to this would scale for 10, 20, 100 customers. Maybe consider using just one database but design it to handle multiple customers, i.e. for each piece of data also store the customer ID next to it.

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clear before. I am in fact using single server even now. Right now - single server, 3 applications, 3 databases!